# React ref assignment inconsistencies when using a mapping function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a virtualized scrolling component in React, and using refs with a recycled observer to notify the app when to prepare another batch of data. Inside my Grid component, I map over the current batch of data and assign a ref to a sentinel div, except that ref returns null in componentDidMount(). I don't understand why since componentDidMount fires after render executes, so the reference should be available.

The only workaround to this I've found is using this janky solution in my componentDidMount: `setTimeout(() => this.observer.observe(this.targetRef.current), 0);`.

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      batch: []
    };

    this.observer = null;
    this.targetRef = null;

    this.lastRowFirstVisible =
      props.rowCount * props.columnCount - props.columnCount;

    this.config = {
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1
    };

    this.setTargetRef = element => {
      this.targetRef = element;
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { startIndex, numberToDisplay } = this.props;
    this.setBatch(startIndex, numberToDisplay);

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, self) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          console.log(entry);
          // self.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    }, this.config);

    setTimeout(() => this.observer.observe(this.targetRef), 0);
  }

  setBatch = (startIndex, numberToDisplay) => {
    const batch = this.getBatch(startIndex, numberToDisplay);
    this.setState({ batch });
  };

  getBatch = (startIndex, numberToDisplay) => {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return data.slice(startIndex, numberToDisplay);
  };

  // TO DO
  updateObserver = () => {
    this.observer.observe(this.targetRef.current);
  };

  render() {
    const { lastRowFirstVisible } = this;
    const { batch } = this.state;
    const { elementWidth, elementHeight } = this.props;
    console.log(lastRowFirstVisible);

    return (
      <>
        {batch.map((element, localIndex) => {
          const { index } = element;
          console.log(localIndex === lastRowFirstVisible);
          return localIndex === lastRowFirstVisible ? (
            <div
              id={index}
              key={index}
              style={{ width: elementWidth, height: elementHeight }}
              className="card"
              ref={this.setTargetRef}
            >
              {this.props.renderRow(element)}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{ width: elementWidth, height: elementHeight }}
              className="card"
            >
              {this.props.renderRow(element)}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Grid;

Expected results: render function finishes executing, assigns DOM node to this.targetRef for use in componentDidMount()
Actual results: this.targetRef is still null in componentDidMount()

Comment: Where is `this.targetRef` defined?

Comment: I added the rest of the component, sorry about the brevity. Current assumption is on the first render batch is an empty array, and so the mapping function never triggers.